# Copy history of commands in matlab

Tags: matlab, command-prompt

I know how to save variables in matlab by this command

```
save
```

and load it by this command

```
load
```

but the question how to copy history of commands in txt file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save` won't save commands, it saves the variables in your current workspace.

MATLAB history is saved in a History.xml file, the directory can be viewed by `prefdir` command.

For plain .txt command, just press up-arrow, and select-all from the history small list, copy it to whatever place you want. You may find [this](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html) documentation helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you do not have access to the admin folders or don't have required previleges,here's a simple method that worked for me,accidentally.

Go to the command prompt
and press *CNTRL+A* (Select All) and then *CNTRL+C*(Copy)
You will be prompted that :

***It is not possible to show 13xx commands on the screen***,

Go ahead anyway.

Then simply *CNTRL + V* (Paste) everything in any text editor.

Voila!

Hope it helps,

Anuj